# How to force Quartz to start now in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, quartz.net, quartz, ihostedservice

I have a job scheduled by Quartz in ASP.NET Core to run every 15 minutes.

I want to run it initially (force Quartz to start now).

I use the following code but it doesn't run the job initially and waits for 15 min to start.

It seems like `.StartNow()` is not working?

```
public class JobSchedulerSimple
{
    public static async Task StartSimpleSync()
    {
        ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        IScheduler sched = await sf.GetScheduler();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<FileJob>()
            .WithIdentity("ID", "ID")
            .Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithIdentity("StartSimpleSync", "ID")
            .StartNow()
            .WithCronSchedule("0 0/15 * * * ?") 
            .Build();

        await sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
        await sched.Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `await sched.TriggerJob(job.Key);` this will create a simple trigger with immediate fire time and run once behavior under the hood.

For cron trigger `StartNow()` just means the start of calculation of fires, it still will follow the schedule which is not "right now".